# I hope your internet's working

Tags: computer-puzzle

I'm new to this StackExchange - I'm more active on programming stack exchanges. So here's a computer-themed puzzle:

`4K5L3RdR-PASTE`
Find the code (6 numbers)

That's it. I'll leave you with one clue - The title.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any tags that suit what this question is about exactly.

Comment: It's quite possible that there is no other needed tags too. Only you know for now ;P. Also although it was needed to say the goal is to find the code, saying how long and what kind of characters are in it was not. It all depends on how easy you want your puzzle to be.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how long the code is. You find the entire thing at once.

Comment: Is `8c-50` a typo?

Comment: [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: For future treasure hunts I would recommend making use of SE's instance of image hosting at i.stack.imgur to prevent link rot.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan Yes.

Comment: @2012rcampion This was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 28):

The answer could have been

> $941184$

But is actually

> $1238476$

Because

> If you go to [pastebin.com/4K5L3RdR](http://pastebin.com/4K5L3RdR) you find:
>
> ```
> 89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a 00 00 00 0d 49 48 44 52
> 00 00 00 22 00 00 00 16 08 06 00 00 00 a5 ac 4e
> 79 00 00 00 79 49 44 41 54 78 da 63 61 60 60 f8
> cf 00 01 8c-50 1a c6 47 07 d4 96 47 e1 b3 30 0c
> 12 c0 82 c7 e5 0c 38 7c 48 48 9e d8 10 22 e8 90
> 41 13 22 ff 89 d4 fb 9f 9a f2 83 3a 44 70 a5 05
> 6a e5 22 ac 69 6c 48 84 c8 7f 4a 72 01 09 ea 06
> 5f 1a 61 24 33 6d 90 2b 8f 55 fd a0 0a 11 4a eb
> 0e 9a 27 d6 01 4f 23 74 09 81 21 55 d7 90 5a ae
> 8c dc 10 21 b5 64 1d 79 69 64 78 86 08 00 ce b8
> 19 58 95 d4 60 0b 00 00 00 2d 74 45 58 74 53 6f
> 66 74 77 61 72 65 00 62 79 2e 62 6c 6f 6f 64 64
> 79 2e 63 72 79 70 74 6f 2e 69 6d 61 67 65 2e 50
> 4e 47 32 34 45 6e 63 6f 64 65 72 a8 06 7f ee 00
> 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82
> ```
>
> Which looks like hexadecimal (except for a lone '-', which I presume is a typo.
>
>  converting that to bytes one sees that it starts with
>
> ```
> \x89PNG\r\n
> ```
>
> and ends with
>
> ```
> tEXtSoftware\x00by.blooddy.crypto.image.PNG24Encoder¨\x06\x7fî\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND®B`\x82
> ```
>
> Writing it to a file with a .png extension yields the image:
>  [image: numbers]
>
>  Originally it was stated the number we sought would have six digits, and since this was not a six digit number I presumed that we needed to multiply, which gave $941184$, however it was not the case.

Comment: I'd argue that the first number is correct, but with a line break

Comment: The first number is correct. I just don't seem to be able to count anymore :(

Comment: @Challenger5 If an answer has solved your problem, please click the green checkmark after waiting for 12 minutes (you have done so).

Answer (score 2):

Question at this stage can be said to be too braod with multiple answers

Here is one -

> Say A=1, B=2... Performing multiplication gives 171072. i.e. taking only characters Which are 6 digits. 11*12*18*4*18(K*L*R*D*R)

Comment: Might look broad, but I have an inkling my answer is more fitting.

Comment: Yes. Posted almost at the same time. Though not sure how the any of the answer can relate to the title.

Comment: Well, one needs a working internet connection to do what I did (although one also needs one to view the question!)

Comment: Even I used internet lol Not very good at math :D