# Treasure hunt of the century

Tags: cipher, treasure-hunt

Will you help my find the treasure?
I just can't find it!

The only hint I have is
Paste->e28DSjPF

Note

> Inspired by Challenger5's puzzle
>  [I hope your internet's working](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45177/i-hope-your-internets-working)

Comment: I think you should add a note saying inspired by chaser5s puzzle

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Trust me, I really wanted too, but I was afraid that would give too big a clue on to how to start the puzzle :/(Did you mean challenger5?)

Comment: Nice little puzzle - I would recommend using i.stack.imgur for future treasure hunts to prevent link rot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using [Jonathan's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45179/26960) of the Previous riddle:

> go to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/e28DSjPF

where you can see:

> Okk, I think I am getting closer to the treasure!
> I just found another clue!
> ************************************************
> The next paste is too fast for this bin. Where might it be?
> **yisaqugozi.md**

> I think the "too fast" is relevant. Not sure.

UPDATE:

> Yeah, the "too fast" was a key. I looked up similar pages as Pastebin ("related:pastebin.com")  and there was HasteBin so : http://hastebin.com/yisaqugozi.md

Printed :

> Alright! We must be getting closee!
> *********************************************
> 1-1 = ?
>  ?90a5ec17f8d14a14#QWaXipJ0snQIZHdQDMlS66N8psrm+jjT45GSISkoj+8=

UPDATE 2:
Thanks to [Jaydm's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45185/26960):

> pasting the url piece into zerobin :   https://zerobin.net/?90a5ec17f8d14a14#QWaXipJ0snQIZHdQDMlS66N8psrm+jjT45GSISkoj+8=

We get:

> Cool I just found the legendaryy treasure!
>  ********************************
> tlFKEv3czQ/CMjii235uag==
> ********************************
>
> But looks like I need a key to open it.
> Did you see any hints to where the key might be on your way here?
>
> Also, the key hole seems a little bit weird. Not sure how to use the key.
> Maybe I should ask about it to the master locksmith Rijndael the 128th who  lives in the city of Ecb.

UPDATE 3 AND LAST

so using [this](https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/) decrypt tool:

> The key is "key" thanks to @oleslaw comment down here
> The algorithm is Rijndael-128
> Mode is ECB
> Content is "tlFKEv3czQ/CMjii235uag== "

The treasure is:

> Lots of gold!

Comment: Going good! +1 for the hastebin. The last one is too broad to answer. There should have been some hint to get it. You can replace ? with 1-1 and then remove the letters and just keep the numbers and operators to solve it. :)

Comment: Maybe thinking a little too much there. The hint pattern did not change at all.

Comment: The double letters in the messages spell "key".

Comment: @oleslaw I didnt notice de K! :D

Comment: Brilliant work.

Comment: Good teamwork everyone! I hope it was fun. I know it was not too hard and there were many hints, but I like to keep my puzzles easy and accessible to all.

Comment: @stackreader I liked it. thanks Jaydm26, oleslaw and Jonathan for their help

Comment: Always glad to help :)

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE

> Pasted link on Zerobin
> Cool I just found the legendaryy treasure!
> ********************************
>
> tlFKEv3czQ/CMjii235uag==
> ********************************
>
> But looks like I need a key to open it.
> Did you see any hints to where the key might be on your way here?
>
> Also, the key hole seems a little bit weird. Not sure how to use the key.
> Maybe I should ask about it to the master locksmith Rijndael the 128th who lives in the city of Ecb.